# Lightning Community - Landing Page/Home Page

Tags: community, lightning

**Requirement** We have created a Lightning Community with a Lightning Template Napili. However, we would like to setup a landing page once you open up the community. The landing page is different from the Home page as it's a page showing a disclaimer. After which the user can login as a guest or login as a community member. After logging in as guest or logging in as community user, you should be redirected towards the actual community Home Page.

**Configuration**
Thus looking at the Site from the Lightning Community, you can setup an 'Active Site Home Page'. For which we have created a custom page which basically should redirect you towards the VF containing the disclaimer.

**Issue**
However, this is not working. When entering the URL of community, you are always redirected towards the Lightning Home Page. It seems like the site option 'Active Site Home Page' is being skipped. Is that true? Is there any other way to achieve the above?

Comment: Did you setup URL redirect for your site to the custom Visualforce page that you are talking about?

Comment: Correct. Landing page is VF. Community is Lightning Community. So redirect should happen once to VF page where disclaimer needs to be accepted. Afterwards standard lightning community page should be the 'home page' thus no redirect anymore towarda VF page.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand your comment. Did you setup the url redirect? and is it still happening with url redirect? I am trying to do something similar to what you are requesting in my dev edition org and I will post here if it works.

Comment: Appologies for the confusion. The Active Site Hone Page has been changed towards a custom VF page with a controller behind. The controller will redirect first towards the Disclaimer VF page and should then navigate towards the Lightning community. So its not the url redirect that has been used. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Ok. Here is what I was able to do on my side based on the details from the question: User enters the url in browser and he is shown a VF page which contains a hyperlink(you can do disclaimer or whatever here), once clicking on it user will be taken to communities login page and once entering credentials, user is taken to Napili template home page. Is this something close to what you are looking for?

Comment: Correct! That sounds like what we are looking for. Could you share some more details?

Comment: I just posted answer with steps. Let me know for any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I did in my developer edition sandbox based on what you provided in the comments and question:

1. Created a community and selected template as Napili.
2. When you create community, It creates a site also go to site(Settings->Develop->Sites)
3. Here add the custom VF page you built(Site Visualforce Pages section).
4. Active Site Homepage should be "CommunitiesLanding"
5. Add a URL redirect for the site as something like below(replace 'SimplePage' with your Disclaimer page):

   [image]
6. On your disclaimer page, wherever you want to display community login url, use something like this:

   ```
   <apex:outputLink value="/CommunitiesLogin"> Community Login</apex:outputLink>
   ```

so with all this what will happen is :

1. User enters url for the site in the browser.
2. User is shown the SimplePage because we set the URL redirect for the site to this page in the above screenshot.
3. This page shows a hyperlink and clicking on it will take user to community login page.
4. Entering credentials will take user to Community home page(Because Active Site Home page is set to "CommunitiesLanding").

Here on step 2, looks like you want to show disclaimer info and other stuff.

Comment: Thanks @javanoob! However, had to close my browser and clear cache before I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

The other way I would do this is via login flows .

> A login flow provides the ability to build custom business processes and invoke them as users log in to the system.

The only caveat is it uses salesforce standard screen but you can build a screen using visual worlflow to force users to agree for an agreement .

Comment: Right but then you are already loggin in. It's the idea that the visitor of the community first sees this disclaimer page. So that he 'accepts' the conditions by then 'loggin in as a community member' or logging in as a guest (thus visiting the public pages).

Comment: Other thing i can think of is to use page variations based on profile ? Does it support guest profile .Have you explored that .It might be useful to see if different page variations are possible for same page .Guest User profile will have different and logged in user different .There might be a custom component to accept conditions

Comment: Guest user profile is not supported with the page variations. It would also mean to set the disclaimer et cetera on the home page. Rather then a first time landing page. Although a custom component could check if the disclaimer was already shown. Problem is then that you have the search functionality visible as its youe home page. Appreciate your help!